# If an impulse is modeled by a random variable x with this density function, how to calculate the prob that...

Tags: probability

If an impulse is modeled by a random variable x with this density function,

**a**) how to calculate the probability that exactly $3$ of $90$ independent sample are $< 0.3$?

**b**) What is the medium intensity of an impulse?

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}(2/9)*x &\mbox{if } x \in (0,3)\\ 0&\mbox{else}\end{cases}$$

For the point **B,** i think that I could use the the integral from $0$ to $3$ of $x\cdot f(x)$. Should I?

For the point **A,** what is the best strategy to use? Should I answer this question using the Bernoulli experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Here, the *binomial distribution* is the right approach: we have $90$ Bernoulli trials.

The probability that an impulse is $\lt 0.3$ is equal to
$$\int_0^{0.3}\frac{2}{9}x\,dx.$$
Calculate. The integral turns  out to be $0.01$.

The probability that exactly $3$ in a sample of $90$ are less that $0.3$ is therefore equal to
$$\binom{90}{3}(0.01)^3 (0.99)^{87}.$$

As a slight complication, we can use the *Poisson* distribution to approximate the Binomial. If you are familiar with the Poisson, you could use as an approximation the probability that a Poisson with parameter $\lambda=(90)(0.01)$ takes on value $3$. This is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^3}{3!}$.

However, the Binomial gives the *exact* answer.

b) What the second problem asks for is not clear from the wording. There are two standard measures of "average" location, the **mean** and the **median**. You used the word "medium," which is not a standard term.

The mean is given by the expression
$$\int_0^3 xf(x)\,dx,$$
where $f(x)$ is your density function.

If $X$ is your random variable, then the median of $X$ is the number $m$ such that $\Pr(X\le m)=\frac{1}{2}$. So we want
$$\int_0^m \frac{2}{9}x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Integrate. We get $\frac{m^2}{9}=\frac{1}{2}$, which yields $m=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: The reason for an approximation by the Poisson distribution is the easier way of obtaining a numerical answer I assume? (Because a normal distribution wouldn't help you evaluating it by hand.)

Comment: The probability of "success" here is $0.01$, and there are $90$ trials. The normal approximation, in this setting, can be rather poor, so it is definitely not appropriate. In the old days, when computation was done by hand, one would routinely use the Poisson approximation to the binomial when it is suitable. Nowadays, calculation is much easier, so approximations are less important than they used to be.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.